# How to add "Refresh" option to right click menu in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, menu, pcmanfm

I have many users at the place I work, expressing the notion of switching to Ubuntu.  Most of them, for whatever weird reason wanting to know if its possible to have **`refresh`** added when you right click on the desktop.

Is that possible?

Comment: Refresh *what*? Icons, like Windows? I doubt that has any functionality in Win 7, etc. these days...

Comment: @izx Yes, refresh icons, and the desktop.  Windows 7 still has that.

Comment: I know it does, but it doesn't  seem to *do* anything :/

Comment: Why don't you try F5 or Ctrl+R  Keys. It is better to use keyboard often.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To add refresh command to right click context menu in Ubuntu 11.10 , install nautilus – refresh by running following commands in the terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nae-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-refresh
```

Once the package is installed, run following commands to restart nautilus or log out and log back in to see the changes.

```
nautilus -q
```

Comment: When I try the first command I get, E: Unable to locate package lineakd

Comment: Can you supply a link? Everything I tried is not working.

Comment: when I try to install using USC, I get an error about unmet dependencies.

Comment: I updated my answer which a more simple approach.Try that instead :)

Comment: Lubuntu doesn't ship Nautilus, so I can't imagine how  it works perfectly...

Comment: Obviously he has Nautilus installed...

Comment: @Nick Even if, will not work... Not even he will set it as default browser. You are free to test it. :) Your answer might fit better [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343719/how-to-get-a-refresh-right-click-action?lq=1). Sincerely, ...

Comment: @Mitch Please, can you make some light relating to [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156201/how-to-add-refresh-option-to-right-click-menu-in-lubuntu/345149#comment449552_157536)? This method worked for you in Lubuntu if you have installed Nautilus? If yes, I would like to know how, because for me it doesn't...

Comment: @RaduRădeanu that was done in lubuntu 11.10, I don;t know that it will work with newer releases of lubuntu or Nautilus for that matter.  Back then I tried, and it worked, even 2 people switched to Ubuntu because of it.

Answer (score 5):

The default file browser in **Lubuntu** is [**PCManFM**](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM). So, if there are some possibilities to "refresh" desktop in Lubuntu, these should act on PCManFM. Thus, looking at the manual page of PCManFM (`man pcmanfm`), I found that running the following command(s) in terminal (`lxterminal`), the desktop will refresh

```
pcmanfm --desktop-off && pcmanfm --desktop --profile lubuntu
```

So far, so good; there is only left to do somehow to run this command from right click menu from the desktop. This can be done in 3 steps:

1. Create a new small script, let say `refresh.sh`, with the following two lines inside:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   pcmanfm --desktop-off && pcmanfm --desktop --profile lubuntu
   ```

   Don't forget to make it executable:

   ```
   chmod +x /path/to/script/refresh.sh
   ```
2. On the desktop, right click and select **Desktop Preferences**, click **Advanced** in the new opened window and tick **Show menus provided by window managers when desktop is clicked**.

   [image: desktop preferences]
3. Using the following command in terminal:

   ```
   sudo -i leafpad /usr/share/lubuntu/openbox/menu.xml
   ```

   edit the opened file `/usr/share/lubuntu/openbox/menu.xml` as follow (you only have to add the bold text and to use the right path for the script created at 1st step):

```
...
  <separator label="System" />
  <menu id="system-menu" icon="/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/categories/applications-system.png" />
  <item label="Refresh">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>/path/to/script/refresh.sh</command>
    </action>
  </item>
  <item label="Log Out">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>lubuntu-logout</command>
    </action>
  </item>
</menu>

</openbox_menu>
```

The result, as I tested in **Lubuntu 13.04**: (Make sure that you logout, and log back in for changes to take effect).

[image: refresh desktop in lubuntu]

<sup>(Sorry for the low quality of the animated gif, but I just don't have time to find something better for the moment)</sup>

Comment: This is great.  Does it only work on 13.04?  I just tried it on 12.10, but no go.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Mich As I said, I tested in Lubuntu 13.04. Try to play with `pcmanfm --desktop --profile lubuntu`, use only `pcmanfm --desktop` or another profile... After editing `/usr/share/lubuntu/openbox/menu.xml` file a re-login is required.

Comment: Yes it does. 12.10, and 12.04. Thanks.