# How to get a "refresh" right click action?

Tags: nautilus

I'm new to Ubuntu 13.04. I want a 'refresh' option, like in Windows when you right click on desktop. Can anyone help me to get that option in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to install the old nautilus python script for Ubuntu 12.04 **(nautilus-refresh)** from the [dr3mro/nautilus-actions-extra](https://launchpad.net/~dr3mro/+archive/nautilus-actions-extra) PPA. ([Dr. Amr Osman](https://launchpad.net/~dr3mro)).

1. Open a Terminal window and type the following to install the necessary packages.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-nautilus xautomation wget
   ```
2. Create a folder to download the deb package.

   ```
   mkdir ~/Downloads/refresh
   cd ~/Downloads/refresh
   ```
3. Download the `nautilus-refresh_0.6~ppa1-0~11~precise1_all.deb` package from Launchpad.

   ```
   wget https://launchpad.net/~dr3mro/+archive/nautilus-actions-extra/+files/nautilus-refresh_0.6~ppa1-0~11~precise1_all.deb
   ```
4. If you are running Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit.. create the following soft link.

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
   ```

   **NOTE:**: If you are running 32-bit you can skip the step 4.
5. Intall the deb package.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i nautilus-refresh_0.6~ppa1-0~11~precise1_all.deb
   ```
6. Finally you can logout and login to see the changes.

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12):

When in any folder (this includes the desktop), hit the <kbd>F5</kbd> key to refresh.

To also add the refresh option to the right-click menu, check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/157536/147044) (thanks Saurav Kumar).

Answer (score 6):

This is not necessary because items added to the `~/Desktop` folder are added to the desktop automatically. This is most likely a bad habit from Windows.

If you really need to, press <kbd>F5</kbd>.