# How to manage package from previous Ubuntu versions

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I have Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr). This output should clarify what I'm referring to

```
$>dpkg -l | grep raring
ii  ezame                                                                0.5~raring-1                                        all          Eza's Menu Editor
ii  nautilus-open-as-root                                                3.6.0-0~9~raring1                                   all          nautilus-open-as-root
ii  nautilus-open-terminal-here                                          3.6.0-0~9~raring1                                   all          nautilus-open-terminal-here
ii  nautilus-refresh                                                     3.6.0-0~9~raring1                                   all          For those who are comming from windows world and misses the refresh option .. here it is finally lands to ubuntu  by Dr. Amr osman <dr3mro@gmail.com>
ii  tlp                                                                  0.4-1~raring                                        all          Save battery power on laptops
ii  tlp-rdw                                                              0.4-1~raring                                        all          Radio device wizard
ii  ubuntu-wallpapers-raring                                             14.04.0.1-0ubuntu1                                  all          Ubuntu 13.04 Wallpapers
ii  virtualbox-4.3                                                       4.3.10-93012~Ubuntu~raring                          amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
```

Why do these packages have a raring reference? How can I update them to the new Trusty versions?

Answer (score 2):

The packages have a "raring" reference for different reasons. Most of them appear to be installed from PPA's [such as this](https://askubuntu.com/q/343719/15341). These must be manually handled when Ubuntu is updated.

Looking at your software sources, you should see the relevant PPA sources. You will have to manually update them to your current version, or you could use a [tool like this](https://askubuntu.com/q/42895/15341). The PPA may not have packages available for your current version though, which is something that the tool will check.

The wallpapers package is just left over from when Raring was installed. The `ubuntu-wallpapers` package will automatically install the current one,  `ubuntu-wallpapers-trusty`. You can remove the Raring version if you don't want it.

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade those packages to their **latest version present in their repository**, run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install <package_1> <package_2> <package_3> ...
```

But this doesn't mean that you'll get a `Trusty` version, nor that you'll get the very latest version.

The former it's simply because the package might have not been updated since `Raring`.

The latter it's simply because the mantainer of the package (or just the `PPA`, but this is more rare) might have changed in the meantime, and the latest packages might be found in another `PPA`.

For example: your `ezame`'s version (if you're using [this](https://launchpad.net/~caldas-lopes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA) it's the latest version present in the repository (i.e.: it never got updated after `Raring` in that repository). If there aren't other `PPAs` mantaining it, the `Raring` version is the latest version.