# How do I add a refresh option in the right click menu in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

I'd like to have an option on the **right-click menu** to refresh Nautilus.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a "refresh" right click action?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343719/how-to-get-a-refresh-right-click-action)

Comment: @CharlesGreen that is a different scenario with Ubuntu 13.04, and this is 16.04. I don't think the both are same. Anyway thanks for notifying.

Comment: You are correct - the content is a bit dated, and there is no current refresh available on launchpad (that I found)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Refresh button for Nautilus on right-click menu**

[image]

- You will need a to download `xdotool` and `nautilus-actions`:

  ```
  sudo apt install xdotool nautilus-actions
  ```
- Open `nautilus-actions` and do the following:

  1. Create a new action and change it's name to *Refresh*
  2. On the *Action* tab, enable `Display item in location context menu`
  3. On the *Command* tab set the *Path* to `/usr/bin/xdotool`, *Parameters* to `key F5`.
  4. Save your changes.
  5. Now go to Nautilus Action's *Edit > Preferences* and get both options at *Runtime preferences > Nautilus menu layout* deselected.
  6. Open a terminal and run `nautilus -q`
  7. Done! Open Nautilus and try it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Also works on 18.04, but nautilus-actions was renamed to filemanager-actions.
Still waiting for filemanager-actions to be added to the repos, but it's available on a development PPA as a workaround:

https://launchpad.net/~tomtomtom/+archive/ubuntu/filemanager-actions

Ref:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1768597

filemanager-actions interface is slightly different.  Updated instructions (with thanks to above).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tomtomtom/filemanager-actions
sudo apt update
sudo apt install filemanager-actions xdotool

# Run with (as user):
fma-config-tool
```

Once installed, open filemanager-actions with fma-config-tool and do the following:

To Create the new "Refresh" option:

- 'Define a new action' and change its name to Refresh
- On the Action tab, enable 'Display item in location context menu'
- On the Command tab set the Path to /usr/bin/xdotool, Parameters, type in 'key F5' without quotes.
- Save your changes with File/Save.

To set the context menu to show directly, and not in a sub-menu:

- In top menu, under 'Filemanager-Actions Configuration Tool' select
  'Preferences'
- In the Runtime preferences tab, disable the following:
- - Create a root 'Filemanager-Actions' menu
- - Add an 'About Filemanager-Actions' item...

Kill all existing nautilus windows with:
Open a terminal and run nautilus -q

Start Nautilus.