# How do I add a refresh option in the right click menu in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nautilus, context-menu

I tried to add instructions in [How do I add a refresh option in the right click menu in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913362/how-do-i-add-a-refresh-option-in-the-right-click-menu-in-ubuntu-16-04) at ubuntu 16.04 but it doesn't work for ubuntu 18.04 bionic.

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? Where did you get stuck? Any error messages?

Comment: nautilus-actions package is not available for bionic. Even I want to add the refresh button manually.

Comment: Yes nautilus-actions package is not available , @M.Becerra  you can follow instruction in my link above.