# How i can add refresh button on right click on ubuntu 18.04.3?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

My ubuntu 18.04.3 is being slow when i do multiple task.i don't feel batter with this problem.i wanna get solution of this problem.if anyone can solve this problem please help me.i will be very glad to you.

Comment: try Alt+F2 and then in the prompt type `r` and hit Enter..

Comment: it's working.but i want a refresh button on desktop.

Comment: F5 have you tried? refresh button on desktop when you right click??

Comment: yes,,,Thank you so much..

Comment: Check this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343719/how-to-get-a-refresh-right-click-action

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a refresh option in the right click menu in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913362/how-do-i-add-a-refresh-option-in-the-right-click-menu-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I improve Ubuntu overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-ubuntu-overall-system-performance)

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is being slow when doing multiple tasks then your options are limited, unless you are capable of upgrading your hardware. Depending on your current specs, upgrading only memory or moving to an SSD drive already can make a large difference in the responsiveness of your system.

If you cannot upgrade your hardware, then your options are limited

1) Try limiting the apps you open at the same time to a maximum extent.

2) Move to a lighter desktop environment that needs less resources and RAM, such as XFCE (Xubuntu), Mate (Ubuntu Mate) or LXDE (Lubuntu).