# Unmet dependencies while adding right click "nautilus-refresh" in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, nautilus, dependencies

I am new to Ubuntu and I am trying to add "Refresh" button on right click by using command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nae-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-refresh
```

But I am getting following error :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nautilus-refresh : Depends: python-nautilus but it is not installable
                    Depends: xautomation but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can someone please help me here since I tried to google it but I am not getting exact solution of it.

I also used "[How to get a "refresh" right click action?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343719/how-to-get-a-refresh-right-click-action)" link to get the things done but it is giving error

Comment: Did you try to contact the author of this third party PPA?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a "refresh" right click action?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343719/how-to-get-a-refresh-right-click-action). Aside from being a dupe this feature is completely unnecessary as Nautilus will "refresh" itself

Comment: @ElefantPlace I tried doing it but it is giving error                                                  "E: Package 'python-nautilus' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'xautomation' has no installation candidate"

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of the command `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both packages are in the Ubuntu universe repository. Enable this repository in Software & Updates as per screen-shot below.

[image]

After that

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-refresh
```

Comment: I am getting following error now : Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nautilus-refresh

Comment: Is the universe repository enabled?

Comment: I checked in software and updates & found everything similar to image shared by you. Does this means that universe repository is enabled. I am sorry to ask this but I am really new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, Finally I was able to slove the issue by using following steps : 1. As mentioned by A.B., when I was closing the "Software & Updates", I was getting error of  **failed to download repository information and to check Internet connectivity**, I used http://askubuntu.com/questions/297222/software-updater-failed-to-download-repository-information solution posted by Matthew and it worked.  2.  I followed http://askubuntu.com/questions/156201/how-to-add-refresh-option-to-right-click-menu-in-lubuntu answered by Nickolas to solve my problem. A BIG THANKS TO A.B., Matthew,  Nickolas

Comment: I already did that @A.B.  Since I was not able to update software, I was not able to install other softwares too like R and VLC and was getting list of dependencies while installing them.  But now, I everything is working great.

Comment: @KartikeyaPandey Ok ;) in other words: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)